# SetGlobal in execute in GAMS

Tags: global, gams-math

Consider I want to execute to parameter (paramter1 and parameter2). I do the following:

```
$onEcho > Textfile.txt
par = parameter1   rng = parameter1!A1
par = parameter2   rng = parameter2!A1
$offEcho

execute_unload 'export.gdx', parameter1 parameter2;
```

But instead of writing that line two times, could I do something like this:

```
$setGlobal Parameter parameter1 parameter2

$onEcho > Textfile.txt
par = %parameter%   rng = %parameter%!A1
$offEcho

execute_unload 'export.gdx', %parameter%;
```

However, this code does not work. How can I specify mine parameters one place instead of writing them mulitple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GAMS you can define [macros](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_DollarControlOptions.html#INDEX_macro), but for your purpose, [$batInclude](https://www.gams.com/33/docs/UG_DollarControlOptions.html#DOLLARbatinclude) might be better:

```
$onEchoV > execUnload.inc
$echo par = %1   rng = %1!A1 > Textfile.txt
execute_unload 'export.gdx', %1;
$offEcho

$batInclude execUnload.inc parameter1
$batInclude execUnload.inc parameter2
```

---

EDIT: Now, that I understood your question better, after discussing it in the comments, here is a new solution using the [put facility](https://www.gams.com/33/docs/UG_Put.html):

```
$setGlobal Parameter parameter1, parameter2

Set exportPars / %Parameter% /;

File fx / 'Textfile.txt' /;
put fx;


loop(exportPars,
   put 'par = ' exportPars.tl:0 '   rng = ' exportPars.tl:0 '!A1' /;
);

execute_unload 'export.gdx', %Parameter%;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I only have parameter2 in my GDX file, when I use your code. I want both parameter1 and parameter2. Do I do something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, then I got it wrong. Each batinclude will write its own gdx file, so the second one will overwrite the first one. The same should actually happen with Textfile.txt in my code. So, what you actually want in the end is one text file with two lines and one gdx file with two symbols?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :-)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: One question: If I want to execute as a .xlsx file - for instance by inserting the following line at the end: "execute 'gdxxrw export.gdx output=export.xlsx @Textfile.txt'", then I have to run the files two times. Is it possible to get the excel file only by running it one time?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that. Which files do you have to run two times?